# Pandas Groupby: keep only rows with same values in column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a list comprising hundreds of corporate investments from a large bond universum. Each bond is assigned a recommendation, depending on the seniority of the investment. Say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BOND': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 
                        2: 'B', 3: 'B', 
                        4: 'C', 5: 'C', }, 
               'STATUS': {0: 'SENIOR', 1: 'SUBORDINATED',
                          2: 'SENIOR', 3: 'SUBORDINATED',
                          4: 'SENIOR', 5: 'SUBORDINATED',
                          },
               'STRATEGY': {0: 'BUY', 1: 'SELL',
                            2: 'SELL', 3: 'SELL',
                            4: 'BUY', 5: 'SELL',
                           }})



    BOND    STATUS       STRATEGY
0   A       SENIOR       BUY
1   A       SUBORDINATED SELL
2   B       SENIOR       SELL
3   B       SUBORDINATED SELL
4   C       SENIOR       BUY
5   C       SUBORDINATED SELL
```

How am I able to select only those bonds that have a SELL recommendation in the column "STRATEGY" for all possible types in the column "STATUS"? In this example, bond B fulfills these criteria. Essentially, my desired output should look like the following:

```
    BOND    STATUS       STRATEGY
2   B       SENIOR       SELL
3   B       SUBORDINATED SELL
```

Pretty sure this can be arranged with Panda's in-build function "groupby". Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an absolute match of all values in the group to have `SELL`, you can use [`groupby.transform('all')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
out = df[df['STRATEGY'].eq('SELL').groupby(df['BOND']).transform('all')]
```

Or with [`groupby.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html):

```
s = df['STRATEGY'].eq('SELL').groupby(df['BOND']).all()

out = df[df['BOND'].isin(s[s].index)]
```

Output:

```
  BOND        STATUS STRATEGY
2    B        SENIOR     SELL
3    B  SUBORDINATED     SELL
```

If for some reason you can have multiple times the same STATUS with different strategies, you can use a `set` comparison (here per group):

```
s1 = df[df['STRATEGY'].eq('SELL')].groupby('BOND')['STATUS'].agg(set)
s2 = df.groupby('BOND')['STATUS'].agg(set)

s = s1.eq(s2)
out = df[df['BOND'].isin(s[s].index)]
```

Or comparing each group to the overall possible strategies in the column:

```
s1 = df[df['STRATEGY'].eq('SELL')].groupby('BOND')['STATUS'].agg(set)
s2 = set(df['STATUS'])

s = s1.eq(s2)
out = df[df['BOND'].isin(s[s].index)]
```

Alternative input:

```
  BOND        STATUS STRATEGY
0    A        SENIOR      BUY
1    A  SUBORDINATED     SELL
2    B        SENIOR     SELL
3    B  SUBORDINATED     SELL
4    C        SENIOR      BUY
5    C        SENIOR     SELL
6    C  SUBORDINATED     SELL
7    D  SUBORDINATED     SELL
```

Output (per group):

```
  BOND        STATUS STRATEGY
2    B        SENIOR     SELL
3    B  SUBORDINATED     SELL
4    C        SENIOR      BUY # C was selected as there is at
5    C        SENIOR     SELL # least one SELL per STATUS
6    C  SUBORDINATED     SELL
7    D  SUBORDINATED     SELL # D is included as there is no SENIOR in the group
```

Output (overall):

Here D is omitted as there is no match for 'SENIOR'

```
  BOND        STATUS STRATEGY
2    B        SENIOR     SELL
3    B  SUBORDINATED     SELL
4    C        SENIOR      BUY
5    C        SENIOR     SELL
6    C  SUBORDINATED     SELL
```

Answer (score 2):

If need test all `BOND`s with only `SELL` strategy use:

```
out = df[~df['BOND'].isin(df.loc[df['STRATEGY'].ne('SELL'), 'BOND'])]
print (out)
  BOND        STATUS STRATEGY
2    B        SENIOR     SELL
3    B  SUBORDINATED     SELL
```

If need also test if `BOND` has all possible `STATUS` values add:

```
uniq = set(df['STATUS'])

out = out[out.groupby('BOND')['STATUS'].transform('nunique').eq(len(uniq))]
print (out)
  BOND        STATUS STRATEGY
2    B        SENIOR     SELL
3    B  SUBORDINATED     SELL
```

Different ouput with changed data:

```
print (df)
  BOND        STATUS STRATEGY
0    A        SENIOR      BUY
1    A  SUBORDINATED     SELL
2    B        SENIOR     SELL
3    B  SUBORDINATED     SELL
4    C        SENIOR      BUY
5    C        SENIOR     SELL
6    C  SUBORDINATED     SELL
7    D        SENIOR     SELL
8    D        SENIOR     SELL


out = df[~df['BOND'].isin(df.loc[df['STRATEGY'].ne('SELL'), 'BOND'])]
print (out)
  BOND        STATUS STRATEGY
2    B        SENIOR     SELL
3    B  SUBORDINATED     SELL
7    D        SENIOR     SELL
8    D        SENIOR     SELL
uniq = set(df['STATUS'])

out = out[out.groupby('BOND')['STATUS'].transform('nunique').eq(len(uniq))]
print (out)
  BOND        STATUS STRATEGY
2    B        SENIOR     SELL
3    B  SUBORDINATED     SELL
```